# Why not Deserialize inheritance class

Tags: c#, json, .net, serialization

i have class:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(ParameterConverter))]
    public Parameter parameter1{ get; set; }
}

public class Parameter
{
   public ParameterType FieldType { get; set; }
};
    
public class FieldParameter : Parameter
{
   public string FieldId { get; set; }
}

public enum ParameterType
{
    Default,
    Field
}
```

and this is example json:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "SomeName"
    "parameter1": {
      "fieldId": "SomeId",
      "fieldType": "Field"
    }
}
```

When deserializing the whole class, I have a problem with property parameter 1. I see only default values.

i use ParameterConverter:

```
public class ParameterConverter: JsonConverter<Parameter>
    {
        public override ParameterRead(
            ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
            Type typeToConvert,
            JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.Null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            Utf8JsonReader startReader = reader;

            using JsonDocument jsonDocument = JsonDocument.ParseValue(ref reader);
            JsonElement jsonObject = jsonDocument.RootElement;
            
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize(ref startReader, typeof(FieldParameter)) as Parameter;
        }

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Parameter value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, value.GetType());
        }
    }
```

but this Converter does not work. Why does the converter not see anything?

i expect to see {"fieldId": "SomeId","fieldType": "Field"}

i am use System.Text.Json.Serialization

Answer (score -1):

I highly recommend you to use Newtonsoft.Json till MS creates a more functional serializer

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var par=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeClass>(json).Dump();

public class SomeClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Parameter parameter1 { get; set; }

    public  SomeClass(JObject parameter1 )
    {
     if(parameter1["fieldId"]!=null) this.parameter1= parameter1.ToObject<FieldParameter>();
     else this.parameter1= parameter1.ToObject<Parameter>();
    }
}
```

and fix Parameter class

```
public class Parameter
{
    public ParameterType fieldType { get; set; }
};
```

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json more slower) and i have Text.Json.Serialization in project

Comment: @gistorx It is better something than nothing. Think again about text.json. It is only good for very simple jsons. You will have to wright a custom converter for the most cases.